# Multivariable polynomial ring injective module?

Tags: polynomials, modules, injective-module

Is the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x_1, \ldots ,x_d]$ an injective module over itself?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not: over an integral domain, injective modules are `divisible`, hence a self-injective integral domain is a `field`.

Comment: Very direct. Another (basically equivalent) way is to show that the injective hull of a domain is its field of fractions (and therefore it would have to be equal to its field of fractions.)  An overkill way that I thought of (but don't recommend) is to know that a self-injective Noetherian ring is Artinian (and this ring is not Artinian.)

Comment: I preferred not to mention the injective hull, which is a much less obvious notion for beginners. I was not too  sure whether the Krull dimension could be invoked either.

Comment: Yes, I could not think of a simpler way, and so that only leaves me with harder ways when I suggest alternatives in comments. Although, the injective hull should be taught immediately after defining injective modules and their properties :)

Comment: Thanks so much fellas